# Microcontroller Peak Detection in C using slope

Tags: c, detection, microcontroller

I am making a finger plethysmograph(FP) using an LED and a receiver. The sensor produces an analog pulse waveform that is filtered, amplified and fed into a microcontroller input with a range of 3.3-0V. This signal is converted into its digital form.

Smapling rate is 8MHz, Processor frequency is 26MHz, Precision is 10 or 8 bit.

I am having problems coming up with a robust method for peak detection. I want to be able to detect heart pulses from the finger plethysmograph. I have managed to produce an accurate measurement of heart rate using a threshold method. However, the FP is extremely sensitive to movement and the offset of the signal can change based on movement. However, the peaks of the signal will still show up but with varying voltage offset.

Therefore, I am proposing a peak detection method that uses the slope to detect peaks. In example, if a peak is produced, the slope before and after the maximum point will be positive and negative respectively.

How feasible do you think this method is? Is there an easier way to perform peak detection using a microcontroller?

Comment: Do you think you have the processing juice for a simple Finite Impulse Response filter. Even filtering with simple -1 0 1 0 -1 pattern might help a lot. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_impulse_response

Comment: I am not sure, I would like to avoid ramping up to a more powerful ucontroller due to the low cost and low power functionality of my current one.

Comment: A simple filter as suggested could be as simple as 3 add/subtracts.

Comment: what do you mean by reducing my resampling rate?

Comment: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency. CDs sample at 44kHz to reproduce 20kHz. Hence you should be looking to sample about 12-30Hz, not 8MHz.

Comment: Yes, doing simple slope detection is probably the most efficient and adequate way to do this.  I agree with John that 8MHz should be massively overkill for the signal you are looking at.

Answer (score 0):

You can still introduce detection of false peaks when the device is moved. This will be present whether you are timing average peak duration or applying an FFT (fast Fourier Transform).

With an FFT you should be able to ignore peaks outside the range of frequencies you are considering (ie those < 30 bpm and > 300 bpm, say).

As Kenny suggests, 8MHz might overwhelm a 26MHz chip. Any particular reason for such a high sampling rate?

Comment: Do you think the microcontroller will be able to perform real time FFT on the signal?

Comment: @maknelly timing single peaks takes 1s but taking say 10 would reduce error ~10%. Take more, or an FFT. It won't take more than a 10s. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform.

Comment: Oh in response to your question, it was giving me odd data points of the signals and skipping peaks. I will lower the frequency and investigate but thank you for your input.

Comment: Simple slope detection is ok, but to remove noise you really could better employ the 26MHz in an FFT.

Answer (score 0):

Like some of the comments, I would also recommend lowering your sample rate since you only care about pulse (i.e. heart rate) for now. So, assuming you're going to be looking at resting heart rate, you'll be in the sub-1Hz to 2Hz range (60 BPM = 1Hz), depending on subject health, age, etc.

In order to isolate the frequency range of interest, I would also recommend a simple, low-order digital filter. If you have access to Matlab, you can play around with Digital Filter Design using its Filter Design and Analysis Tool ([Introduction to the FDATool](http://www.mathworks.com/products/signal/demos.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/signal/introfdatooldemo.html)). As you'll find out, Digital Filtering ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_filter)) is not computationally expensive since it is a matter of multiplication and addition.

To answer the detection part of your question, YES, it is certainly feasible to implement peak detection on the plethysmograph waveform within a microcontroller. Taking your example, a slope-based peak detection algorithm would operate on your waveform data, searching for changes in slope, essentially where the slope waveform crosses zero.

Here are a few other things to consider about your application:

- Calculating slope can have a "spread" (i.e. do you find the slope between adjacent samples, or samples which are a few samples apart?)
- What if your peak detection algorithm locates peaks that are too close together, or too far apart, in a physiological sense?
- A Pulse Oximeter ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse_oximetry)) often utilizes LEDs which emit Red and Infrared light. How does the frequency of the LED affect the plethysmograph? (HINT: It may not be significant, but I believe you'll find one wavelength to yield greater amplitudes in your frequency range of interest.)

Of course you'll find a variety of potential algorithms if you do a literature search but I think slope-based detection is great for its simplicity. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you can detect the period using zero crossing, even at 10x oversampling of 10 Hz, you can use a line fit of the quick-n-dirty-edge to find the exact period, and then subtract the new wave's samples in that period with the previous, and get a DC offset.  The period measurement will have the precision of your sample rate.  Doing operations on the time and amplitude-normalized data will be much easier.

This idea is computationally light compared to FFT, which still needs additional data processing.